# TOR services are blocked

Tags: help

TOR services are blocked in Egypt by the government. Even this website can't be accessed without vpn.
 Is there away around this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use many different bridges to bypass the censorship.
You can learn about them here: https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges

---

Also make sure that your Tor Browser Bundle version is the latest. (At the time it is 7.0).
If you can't download directly from https://torproject.org, you can get latest version of Tor by email:
Quoting from https://www.torproject.org/projects/gettor:

> Users can communicate with GetTor robot by sending messages via email. Currently, the best known email address to do this is gettor@torproject.org. This should be the most current and stable GetTor robot as it is operated by Tor Project itself.
>
> To ask for Tor Browser, a user should send an email to GetTor robot with one of the following options in the body of the message:
>
> - windows: If the user needs Tor Browser for Windows.
> - linux: If the user needs Tor Browser for Linux.
> - osx: If the user needs Tor Browser for Mac OS X.

Also you can download it using Twitter:

> You can send a direct message to [@get_tor](https://twitter.com/get_tor) account (you don't need to follow). Send the word **help** in a direct message to learn how to interact with it.